# rDNS for SMTP server locally with Mail hosted by third party

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp

Ok We have a difference of opinion on something and wanted to get some expert advice.

We host our mail with our main domain "OurDomain.net"  with a third part mail provider. We have an in house application that has to be able to send mail out to our clients. The problem is that sometimes the mail is flaky and will stop users from functioning in the program for 30 sec or more and appears to lock up. We have determined that the issue is with the mail piece.

One solution is to use Database mail to queue up outbound emails to send out. The other is to set up an intenal SMTP server and send out mail through it. My fear is that we wil not be able to get rDNS to work properly and most of the mail will be blocked by our various client spam filters. Is it possible to set up the DNS for the servers so that we can send mail out like xx@OurDomain.net using the smtp server in house and still pass the rDNS parameters that are normally set on spam filters?

enquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a failure-mode SMTP was designed to handle, and you have a grasp on the right knob already. The canonical way to solve this is to create an SMTP server configured to forward all email via your 3rd party provider. All the mail will queue up on that system, and **it** will handle the retries needed.

The happy part here is that your 3rd party provider is still the delivering party as far as the receivers are concerned, so your rDNS concerns don't matter.